# Trying to compare access and users from two different CSV's

Tags: powershell, csv

I am importing the following 2 files.

**CSV1 File**

```
UserID      Permission  Role  
A123456 PERM1       Role1  
A123456 PERM1       Role2  
A123456 PERM2       Role2  
A123457 PERM1       Role2  
A123457 PERM2       Role2  
A123458 PERM3       Role3  
A123459 PERM4       Role4  
A123460 PERM5       Role5  
A123461 PERM6       Role6  
A123462 PERM7       Role7  
A123463 PERM8       Role8  
A123464 PERM9       Role9
```

**CSV2 File**

```
UserID  Permission  Role  
A123456 PERM1   NA  
A123456 PERM2   NA  
A123457 PERM1   NA  
A123457 PERM2   NA  
A123458 PERM3   NA  
A123459 PERM4   NA  
A123460 PERM5   NA  
A123461 PERM8   NA  
A123462 PERM7   NA  
A123463 PERM8   NA  
A123464 PERM9   NA  
A123465 PERM99  NA
```

I then run my current script and get the following results

**Current results**

```
UserID  Permission  Role    Permission Compare Results  
A123456 PERM1   Role1   CVS1 and CVS2 Match  
A123456 PERM2   Role2   CVS1 and CVS2 Match  
A123457 PERM1   Role2   CVS1 and CVS2 Match  
A123457 PERM2   Role2   CVS1 and CVS2 Match  
A123458 PERM3   Role3   CVS1 and CVS2 Match  
A123459 PERM4   Role4   CVS1 and CVS2 Match  
A123460 PERM5   Role5   CVS1 and CVS2 Match  
A123462 PERM7   Role7   CVS1 and CVS2 Match  
A123463 PERM8   Role8   CVS1 and CVS2 Match  
A123464 PERM9   Role9   CVS1 and CVS2 Match  
A123461 PERM8   NA      Not in CVS1  
A123465 PERM99  NA      Not in CVS1  
A123456 PERM1   Role2   Not in CVS2  
A123461 PERM6   Role6   Not in CVS2
```

I am trying to get the following results but cannot get the correct results for the userid match. Any ideas?

**Desired Results**

```
UserID  Permission  Role    Permission Compare Results  UserID Match  
A123456 PERM1   Role1   CVS1 and CVS2 Match      CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123456 PERM2   Role2   CVS1 and CVS2 Match      CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123457 PERM1   Role2   CVS1 and CVS2 Match      CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123457 PERM2   Role2   CVS1 and CVS2 Match      CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123458 PERM3   Role3   CVS1 and CVS2 Match      CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123459 PERM4   Role4   CVS1 and CVS2 Match      CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123460 PERM5   Role5   CVS1 and CVS2 Match      CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123462 PERM7   Role7   CVS1 and CVS2 Match      CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123463 PERM8   Role8   CVS1 and CVS2 Match      CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123464 PERM9   Role9   CVS1 and CVS2 Match      CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123461 PERM8   NA      Not in CVS1              CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123465 PERM99  NA      Not in CVS1              CVS2 UserID not in CVS1  
A123456 PERM1   Role2   Not in CVS2              CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match  
A123461 PERM6   Role6   Not in CVS2              CVS1 and CVS2 UserID Match
```

**Current PowerShell script**

```
$APP="CVS2"  ##Name APP
##List from CVS1
Import-Csv file1.csv |
##Concatonate UserID and Permission 
Select-Object *,@{Name="PermissionMatch"; expression={$_.UserID+$_.Permission}} |
##Export to temporary file 
Export-Csv file1revised.csv -NoTypeInformation
##List from Application
Import-Csv file2.csv |
##Concatonate UserID and Permission 
Select-Object *,@{Name="PermissionMatch"; expression={$_.UserID+$_.Permission}} |
##Export to temporary file 
Export-Csv file2revised.csv -NoTypeInformation
##Import both temporary files
$csv1=import-csv file1revised.csv
$csv2=import-csv file2revised.csv
##Compare permissions from both files
$result = (Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $csv2 -ReferenceObject $csv1 -Property PermissionMatch - 
IncludeEqual -PassThru |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '==') {
            $_.SideIndicator = "CSV1 and $APP Match"
        } elseif ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>') {
            $_.SideIndicator = "Not in CVS1"
        } elseif ($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=')  {
            $_.SideIndicator = "Not in $APP"
        }
        $_
    })
##Export Results
$result | select-object -Property UserID, Permission, Role,@{Name="Permission Compare Results"; 
expression={$_.SideIndicator}} | export-csv result.csv -NoTypeInformation

## Remove temporary files
remove-Item file1revised.csv
remove-Item file2revised.csv
```

Comment: Please, don't post images of data. Post the data as text.

Comment: I'd say "No". ;-) Please format your example data as code as well and use the original delimiter.